# Librosa installation in Python

Tags: python, python-import, librosa

I try to install librosa in python. Then I got error with llvmlite lite.

I solved with easy_install llvmlite command.
After that the librosa package is installed successfully.

The issue starts when I importing librosa in Jupiter.

The errors is -

OS Error: could not load shared object file libllvmlite.so

I do not understand this error. The packages are successfully installed but got error when importing.

Any help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think in Linux, .so are shared objects. Restart and try opening your jupyter notebook with super user.